# Error as :Field is not writeable: OpportunityLineItem.Extension__c

Tags: trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

Can any one help me out with this Error.

Error as :

```
Field is not writeable: OpportunityLineItem.Extension__c
```

Error line is :ol.Extension__c=(ol.Extension__c)*0.01;

Im writting an apex trigger to populate the field Extension which is a formula field on opportunitylineitem  and then see itreference three fields of opportunity object (Subtotal,NonpickTotal and Picktotal which are roll up summary field).So how i can get this fields in  opportunitylineitem.

Trigger :

```
trigger Populate_Extension on OpportunityLineItem (Before Insert) {
  List<OpportunityLineItem> ListOpportunityLineItem = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem ol:Trigger.new){
     List<Opportunity> opp= [SELECT Non_Pick_Total__c,Pick_Total__c,Subtotal__c
                                  FROM Opportunity
                                 Where id=:ol.opportunityid];

     if(ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c =='DIE')
     {
       ol.unitprice=0.01;
       ol.Extension__c=(ol.Extension__c)*0.01;
      // Subtotal__c=
       ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=ol.Bin_Item_Code__c;
      } 
     else if(ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c != 'DIE')
     {
      ol.unitprice=1;
       ol.Extension__c=(ol.Quantity)*1;
      // Subtotal__c=
 }      ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=ol.Bin_Item_Code__c;
}
}
```

How should i call the field from opportunity object and assign a value.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Formula fields are not writeable.

Comment: @ BarCotter:Do we have an option writting a trigger on parent object and change the  formula field value of child object.

Comment: If you change the field type so its not a formula field then yes you can do that.

Comment: @Can i call the Roll up summary field from opportunity  object in to opportunity line item and change/ assign the value to it with a roll up summary field.I mean Subtotal__c ,Non pick total and picktotal are roll up summary field.So on condition i need to use as Subtotal=Nonpicktotal nd Subtotal=picktotal  .So how can i call these fields from opportunity in opportunity line item

Comment: I did not understand all of that. If a field is any type of formula, including a roll up summary, then you can not change the value in that field.

Comment: You could update one or more of the components fields that are part of the formula. That would cause the formula field to update if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @BarCotter:As stated we can change the field type .Can i call the Roll up summary fields in the trigger to change/assign the value.

Comment: You can read from the Roll up summary fields but you can not write to them.